# Update UI by code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to update some user control in wpf by code, with no luck.

That's the xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SimuladorNocs.UI.Diagram.PropertiesWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:PropertyGrid="clr-namespace:Deepforest.WPF.Controls"
>
<DockPanel>        
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Width="300" Height="600" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

        <PropertyGrid:PropertyGridControl Height="300"  x:Name="MyPropertyGrid" />

    </StackPanel>     
</DockPanel>
```

and that's the c# code:

```
public void SetInstance(object obj){
    MyPropertyGrid = new PropertyGridControl { Instance = obj, Height = 300 };
    stackPanel.Children.Clear();
    stackPanel.Children.Add(MyPropertyGrid);    }
```

In the end, the property appers to be changing, but I was unable to see the changes in the UI. I also tried to create a new object instead of using the existing MyPropertyGrid, did not work, also tried not clearing the stackpanel without success...

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the specified propertygrid control but it seems that the UI doesn't get updated.  did you try "UpdateLayout()" on that control and on the stack panel itself ?

Answer (score 2):

```
stackPanel.InvalidateVisual();
```

Please add this at the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Swapped out the `PropertyGridControl` for a `Label` and it worked fine. I suggest you do the same. If it works, it's more a question of what the `PropertyGridControl` is doing wrong...

Comment: no, it did not work for me.
try to do that, but make the call to SetInstance() from another usercontrol, when you call from the constructor for example, it works...

Comment: in that case, can you post a full repro that doesn't require external libraries?